# Counting blocks of continuous sequences in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Let´s suppose this situation:

```
CAR     TIME
A       1300
A       1301
A       1302
A       1315
A       1316
A       1317
A       1319
A       1320
B       1321
B       1322
```

I´d like to generate another column, enumerating each trip did by each car.
We consider there´s a new trip every time we get a discontinuity on TIME.

```
CAR     TIME    TRIP
A       1300     1
A       1301     1
A       1302     1
A       1315     2
A       1316     2
A       1317     2
A       1319     3
A       1320     3
B       1321     1
B       1322     1
```

Is there some SQL function to obtain this count ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One additional point: TIME actually is a number representing current date and time - for example 201807250459 is 25-July-2018 04:59. So 201807250500 - 201807250459 should return 1 (one minute) not 41.

Comment: Is there a reason you're storing datetime values as numbers rather than as dates ?

Comment: For legacy reasons ... but probably because it´s easier to watch these values in some cases, such as log files. In fact I see tables storing dates as dates, and tables storing dates as numbers in this schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
SELECT t.car, t.time, MIN(t3.time)
  FROM test t, test t3
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM test t2
                    WHERE t2.car = t.car
                      AND t2.time = t.time - 1)
   AND t3.car = t.car
   AND t3.time >= t.time
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM test t4
                    WHERE t4.car = t3.car
                      AND t4.time = t3.time + 1)
 GROUP BY t.car, t.time
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

The first not-exists finds all the rows that don't have a row for the same car in the previous minute - that is to say, those rows who begin a period for a car.

The later not-exists gets a set of rows that do not have a following row for the same car - i.e. rows that end a period.   The max function finds the least of these (that also are filtered to be greater or equal to the start of the period in question.

Comment: Vinnie, your solution worked well in all the cases mentioned before, with a time of execution of 16.4s, not so fast but not so slow. Though you didn´t create a new column as I originally imagined - that should be an intermediate subquery - you went directly to the next step I was aiming. I´m now going to try to adapt your solution to my real code to see if it´s ok.

Comment: Add an index on the rows car, time and it should be quite fast.   Also you will need to do some tweaking of the time +/- 1 conditions in the sub queries to match how your time is actually encoded.

Comment: Also if you have an outer limit for the length of a trip you can further speed things up by adding ```AND t3.time <= t.time + max_possible_trip``` right above the second subquery.

Comment: Vinnie, I considered Alex´s solution and yours the most helpful ... and in fact Alex presented a more complete solution joining all the pieces of the puzzle with a better performance. Both of you should be voted, but I´m considering your original (and very clear) work on this algorithm to choose your solution.
Many thanks for all you who posted here.

Answer (score 6):

You seems want cumulative approach :

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by car order by grp1) as trp
from (select t.*, sum(case when grp > 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by car order by time) as grp1
      from (select t.*, coalesce((time - lag(time) over (partition by car order by time)), 1) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Yogesh, I´m having troubles with this syntax. For some reason, it´s not accepting the statement "select \*, coalesce (...)". It seems it´s accepting "select t.\*, coalesce (...)" but also there´s the question of datetime to deal.

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga - yes, Oracle requires `*` to be prefixed with a table name or alias if it is not the only thing in the select list. [See the syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. So, did Yogesh probably use another database ?

Answer (score 4):

I would use `row_number()` . . . and `-` to define the groups.  Then, `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by car order by time - seqnum) as trip
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by car order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

I cannot readily think of any alternative that uses fewer than 2 window functions -- or that would likely be faster using `join`s and `group by`s.

Comment: Gordon, you presented a very clean solution using dense_rank to do the hard work and at the first sight it´s working well.

Comment: But I found a pathological case ... If there are multiple lines with same TIME, they are counted as different trips.

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga . . . You can use `dense_rank()` in the subquery if that is an issue with your data.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'd solve this problem:

```
with grp as (
  select row_number() over (partition by CAR order by TIME) rn, a.CAR, a.TIME
  from test a
  where not exists (select * from test b
                    where a.CAR=b.CAR 
                    and to_date(b.TIME, 'YYYYmmDDHH24MI')+1/(24*60) = to_date(a.TIME, 'YYYYmmDDHH24MI'))
)
select t.CAR, t.TIME, (
  select max(rn) from grp where t.CAR=grp.CAR and grp.TIME <= t.TIME
) as trip
from test t
```

the main idea is to select start time for each trip (this is done in CTE `grp`), then use row number as trip identifier

Sample fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a327/10

Comment: Right; it correctly sets the *set number* for every *start time*, but doesn't produce the result Emerson wants (while Yogesh's answer does).

Comment: @Littlefoot hm, why do you think that it produces wrong result?

Comment: I don't think :) I ran your query (on my 11g XE) and got 4 rows as a result, while the OP requires 10 rows (based on example he provided). Apparently, based on SQL Fiddle (I've just clicked it), your query really works which now makes me puzzled because SQL Fiddle also uses 11g XE. Huh? Oh well, never mind. I'll leave this comment for a few minutes so that you'd see it, and then - if you agree - I'll remove my unnecessary comments (and will upvote your answer right now). Sorry.

Comment: @Littlefoot really strange, probably you have something wrong with input data

Comment: Ilya, I´ve tested your solution with my real table and it produced the following values for trip: 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 (this 9 was due to the change from 22:59 to 23:00, that I´ve just commented above.) This seems a good solution if I need to distinguish the records by trip (and in fact, I just need it), but it would not be a solution if I wanted an actual trip count starting by 1.

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga got it, check updated answer - it correctly compares datetimes

Comment: Ilya: the problem with datetimes is now ok.  But it´s not being efficient. I need to test it using some limitation (for example: where CAR = 'A') because my table has a large number of records and it´s not returning after minutes of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the other ideas, including trips crossing an hour boundary but without converting to a date (in case that is significantly slowing things down), and allowing for repeated times in the same trip:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (car, time) as (
            select 'A', 201808151259 from dual -- extra row to go across hour
  union all select 'A', 201808151300 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151301 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151302 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151315 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151316 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151317 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151319 from dual
  union all select 'A', 201808151319 from dual -- extra row for duplicate time
  union all select 'A', 201808151320 from dual
  union all select 'B', 201808151321 from dual
  union all select 'B', 201808151322 from dual
)
-- actual query
select car,
  time,
  dense_rank() over (partition by car order by trip_start) as trip
from (
  select car,
    time,
    max(case when lag_time = time
               or lag_time = time - case when mod(time, 100) = 00 then 41 else 1 end
             then null else time end
    ) over (partition by car order by time) as trip_start
  from (
    select car,
      time,
      lag(time) over (partition by car order by time) as lag_time
    from your_table
 )
)
order by car, time;
```

which gets

```
CAR         TIME         TRIP
--- ------------ ------------
A   201808151259            1
A   201808151300            1
A   201808151301            1
A   201808151302            1
A   201808151315            2
A   201808151316            2
A   201808151317            2
A   201808151319            3
A   201808151319            3
A   201808151320            3
B   201808151321            1
B   201808151322            1
```

The innermost query just gets the original data and the previous time value for each row using `lag()`.

The next query out finds the trip start by treating duplicate and adjacent times - including over an hour boundary, via the nested case expression - as null, and then finding the highest value so far, which ignores the just-generated nulls by default. All contiguous runs of times end up with the same trip-start time:

```
select car,
  time,
  max(case when lag_time = time
             or lag_time = time - case when mod(time, 100) = 00 then 41 else 1 end
           then null else time end
  ) over (partition by car order by time) as trip_start
from (
  select car,
    time,
    lag(time) over (partition by car order by time) as lag_time
  from your_table
)
order by car, time;

CAR         TIME   TRIP_START
--- ------------ ------------
A   201808151259 201808151259
A   201808151300 201808151259
A   201808151301 201808151259
A   201808151302 201808151259
A   201808151315 201808151315
A   201808151316 201808151315
A   201808151317 201808151315
A   201808151319 201808151319
A   201808151319 201808151319
A   201808151320 201808151319
B   201808151321 201808151321
B   201808151322 201808151321
```

The outermost query then uses `dense_rank()` to give the trips consecutive numbering based on their trip-start times.

Comment: Alex, I was not much interested to try your solution once you did a trick using the number 41 ... but the fact is that it worked perfectly with an execution time of 2.3 seconds !

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga - you could convert the numbers to strings and then to dates instead, but that could be a significant amount of extra work. Manipulating them as numbers is maybe less intuitive but should be more efficient. (Of course, the 41 adjustment or the conversion wouldn't be necessary if you were using the right data type to start with *8-)